# PowerApps Web Files returning 404 and 500 errors

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

I'm evaluating PowerApps for our company and am attempting to create a sample Portal application. I've uploaded a couple of images (created a web file and added the image as a note attachment per the documentation) and updated the theme.css file.

Occasionally in the editor the images/style will load correctly but I cannot get them to load when the portal site is viewed in a browser. I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, all with the same result. The default images that are created with the portal work.

I get a 404 for each of the images and a 500 for the theme.css.

I have uploaded other images and they work, I've tried both PNG and JPG.

I'm looking for some suggestions on what else to look at to troubleshoot this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently started working on PowerApps portals and faced the similar issue. To fix this I created "Redirects" for every file I wanted to be served from relative path "assets/images/sample.png".
Open **portal Management App** --> **Redirects** --> Create **New** --> Set **Inbound Url** as relative path --> status code as permanent redirect --> **Redirect Url** as file name (don't forget the leading slash(/)) --> click Save

File SS: 
[image]

Redirect SS: 
[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: I'll have to take a look at this. It seems a bit of a hack (no offense intended) to have to use a redirect in that manner. For my project, I abandoned PowerApps in favor of Betty Blocks, the functionality for the web provided by PowerApps presently just isn't where I need it to be.

Comment: @Chuck.. Yes, its completely your choice to use PAP as a development option. I am working on PAP till now and its fabulous based on my current project requirements. FYI for authentication/authorization, we are using Azure B2C and rest is covered by Dynamics 365 - CDS